# Implementing in-app review API into android app with button click

Tags: android

I am trying to set up the in app reviews in my app but just with a button click to show the app review dialogue. There is some limited info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java
However I am struggling to apply the logic in the docs to achieve my usecase.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The docs say that you should not display the in-app review dialog using a CTA as the dialog may not show, causing a bad user experience.

Comment: What does CTA mean?

Comment: Call to Action - Meaning showing the user a button that is supposed to launch the in-app review like "Rate noe" because the rating may actually never show.

Comment: Quote from the docs: "For example, you should not have a call-to-action option (such as a button) to trigger a review as a user might have already hit their quota and the flow won’t be shown, presenting a broken experience to the user."

Comment: What does it mean by hit their quota?

Comment: Say, for example, Google only allows your app to show the in-app review dialog to a user once a day. If you exceed their quota then your dialog will not show.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotliners.

In your Main Activity

```
private lateinit var reviewInfo: ReviewInfo
private lateinit var manager: ReviewManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setupReviewManager()

    button.setOnClickListener{
        val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
        flow.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for your Review", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun setupReviewManager(){
    manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
    val requestReview = manager.requestReviewFlow()
    requestReview.addOnCompleteListener { request ->
        if (request.isSuccessful) {
            reviewInfo = request.result
        } else {
            Log.d("ReviewException", request.exception.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to test on a device with google play store, also

Note: The ReviewInfo object is only valid for a limited amount of time. Your app should request a ReviewInfo object ahead of time (pre-cache) but only once you are certain that your app will launch the in-app review flow.

Comment: How about Java? If I reproduce your code the app won't build: it tells me `reviewInfo` must be initialized.

Comment: I would be happy if it would just work on a simple button click never mind the complicated flow stuff

Comment: You shouldn't use the toast saying "Thank you". As per https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java the onComplete gets triggered when the flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown. Thus, no matter the result, we continue our app flow.